# Compile error: Sub or Function not defined - I want to add an Enter button to my form

Tags: excel, vba

Compile error: Sub or Function not defined - I want to add an Enter button to my form

[image]

Comment: ok fixed that and now it is showing Run-time error '424': Object required

Comment: How did you define `Sheet1`? Did you mean `WorkSheets("Sheet1")`?

Comment: All done it works now! i have another issue when adding a delete button it is highlighting the "IF lstDisplay.Selected(i) Then":                                                         Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
Dim i As Integer

For i = 0 To Range("A65356").End(xlUp).Row - 1

If lstDisplay.Selected(i) Then

Rows(i + 1).Select

Selection.Delete

End If
Next i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change "STE" to "SET"

It happens to the best of us :-)